# render data in component which getting from react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm new in react and working to get data from redux and render in component.

The issue is that I'm calling API using Axios in the **CarAction.js** file and managing my state in **CarReducer.js** and I want to render data in the **InspectionFom.js** file in **div**. I'm already getting data in console now just want to render in table.

Here is the code of the **InspectionFom.js** file in which I want to render my data in a table and I have an import **CarAction.js** file and calling Action using the dispatch method. I tried to get data using the map function but it's giving me an error.

```
        import { CarAction } from "../../Store/Actions/CarAction";
        import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    
        const InspectionsForm = () => {
            const dispatch = useDispatch();

          useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(CarAction.getInspectedCar());
      }, [dispatch]);
    
          return (
          <div>
          <div className="table-responsive">
              <table className="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Fields</th>
                    <th>Original</th>
                    <th>Repaint</th>
                    <th>PR</th>
                    <th>N/C</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {fieldItems.map((item) => {
                    return (
                      <tr>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>
                          <Form.Check
                            className="radio-size"
                            type="radio"
                            aria-label="radio 1"
                            value="original"
                            name="field"
                          />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Form.Check
                            className="radio-size"
                            type="radio"
                            aria-label="radio 1"
                            value="repaint"
                            name="field"
                          />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Form.Check
                            className="radio-size"
                            type="radio"
                            aria-label="radio 1"
                            value="PR"
                            name="field"
                          />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Form.Check
                            className="radio-size"
                            type="radio"
                            aria-label="radio 1"
                            value="N/C"
                            name="field"
                          />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                  })}
    
                </tbody>
              </table>
    </div>
    
          );
    
    };
```

Here is the code of **CarAction.js**

```
     export const CarAction = {

      getInspectedCar() {
    try {
      return (dispatch) => {
        return axiosInstance
          .post(`user/carRequest/getCarInspectionDetail/1`)
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.data.status === "success") {
              console.log("Successfull Inspection", res.data.data);
              return dispatch({
                type: Constant.getCarInspectionDetails,
                payload: res.data.data,
              });
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Unsuccessfull Inspection", error);

          });
      };
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Exception Car Action", e);
    }
  },
  }
```

Here is the code of **CarReducer.js**:

```
        const INITIAL_STATE = {
  getcarinspectiondetails: []
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

        case Constant.getCarInspectionDetails:
      return {
        ...state,
        getcarinspectiondetails: action.payload
      }

          default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: `fieldItems` doesn't appear to be defined in `InspectionsForm`. Looks like you need to use a `useSelector` hook and pick out the `getcarinspectiondetails` array from state you want to render.

Comment: I also pass is as parameter in  dispatch(CarAction.getInspectedCar(fieldItems)); but it still give same error.

Comment: Can you please provide me the code or example link?

Comment: I think you're missing some reat-redux basics. the `getInspectedCar` doesn't consume any arguments. Can you update how you configure your store, i.e. where the `CarReducer` is combined into a root reducer for the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing pulling data ***out of*** your store. Since you are using a functional component you can use the `useSelector` hook from `react-redux`.

[useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) "Allows you to extract data from the Redux store state, using a selector function."

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const InspectionsForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(CarAction.getInspectedCar());
  }, [dispatch]);

  // Select the getcarinspectiondetails state
  const fieldItems = useSelector(
    state => state.carReducer.getcarinspectiondetails // *
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            ...
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {fieldItems.map((item) => {
              return (
```

***** **NOTE:** This is assuming your carReducer is combined ***at*** the root of your state. Your *actual* state structure may be different.